# How to deduce template return type with another template parameter with explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

I have a (member) function with the following signature:

```
template<Type TypeToAllocate, typename Str>
    Str* allocate();
```

`Type` is an enum and depending on the supplied enum, I want to return different pointers of type `Str`.

Now I am not sure how I can do this. An example code is here:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
enum class Type {
    A,
    B
};

struct Bar{};
struct Baz{};

struct Foo {
    Type t;
    union {
        Bar b;
        Baz bz;
    };
};

struct Util {
std::vector<Foo> foos;

    template<Type TypeToAllocate, typename Str>
    Str* allocate();

};


template<>
    Bar* Util::allocate<Type::A>() {
        Foo& f = foos.emplace_back(Foo{});
        f.t = Type::A;
        f.b = Bar{};
        return &f.b;
    }

int main() {
    Util u{};
    Bar* b = u.allocate<Type::A>(); // this does not work
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T357KTnGd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the role of `Str` in your code. If this was just part of your attempt to map the enum values to either `Bar` or `Baz`, then I think you do not need it.

I would use a trait, that can easily be specialized for different values of `Type`:

```
enum class Type {
    A,
    B
};

struct Bar{};
struct Baz{};

template <Type t> struct TypeMapper;
template <> struct TypeMapper<Type::A> { using type = Bar; };
template <> struct TypeMapper<Type::B> { using type = Baz; };

template <Type t> using TypeMapper_t = TypeMapper<t>::type;

struct Util {
    template<Type t>
    TypeMapper_t<t>* allocate() { 
        return new TypeMapper_t<t>();
    }
};

int main() {
    Util u{};
    Bar* b = u.allocate<Type::A>();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jrzx3933a)

I also suggest you to use `std::variant<Bar,Baz>` instead of the union.

Comment: Thank you very much. i had problems compiling this in msvc though. i had to  put  'typename' infront of the method return type.

Comment: @Raildex yes, my mistake. Alternatively you can use an alias template, see edit